# Excel customer data validation for chars and numbers

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I am trying to validate a combination of char and numbers that looks like this XXXX0000000.

I have tried this formula; =OR((LEFT(B2,3)="XXXX",LEN(B2)=11),AND(LEFT(B2,3)="XXXX",LEN(B2)=11).

The error message I receive is as follows:

[excel error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xYYR.png)

Comment: Your left() function returns 3 characters and you compare it to 4, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Solar Mike is also correct, I was wondering if that was just a typo. You need to do left(B2,4) on the left if using four X's, or change it to XXX if you only want to look at the first 3

Comment: Hi sorry to clarify - I actually want to force users to enter data in a specific row of cells in a sequence like HYPE1234567 i.e. first four characters must be letters then seven digits using custom data validation. Also restrict the total length entered into cell to 11 characters altogether (text (4) and numbers (7) combined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Title**: *"Excel customer data validation for chars and numbers"*

...I have the feeling it's not just about validating `XXXX0000000` but it's about the pattern of characters and numbers. Therefor try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&A1&"</s></t>","//s[translate(substring(.,1,4), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''][string-length()=11][substring(.,5)*0=0]")),"Invalid","Valid")
```

Where:

- `//s[translate(substring(.,1,4), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')='']` - Check if when we translate the first 4 characters to nothing this also equals empty string;
- `[string-length()=11]` - Check that node is 11 characters long;
- `[substring(.,5)*0=0]` - Check that substring from 5th position onwards equals zero when multiplied by zero.

**Note**: `FILTERXML()` is case sensitive and is currently checking for uppercase alpha-chars.

---

**EDIT**:

To use this in data-validation; Ditch the `IF()` since you don't need that in validation and nest the remainder in `NOT()`:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&A1&"</s></t>","//s[translate(substring(.,1,4), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''][string-length()=11][substring(.,5)*0=0]")))
```

When you select your range, make sure the validation rule has the topleft cell in the reference.

Comment: Hi thank you for this, I actually want to force users to enter data in a specific row of cells in a sequence like HYPE1234567

i.e. first four characters must be letters then seven digits using custom data validation. Also restrict the total length entered into cell to 11 characters altogether (text (4) and numbers (7) combined).

Comment: Your samples do not match your requirement. @doom please provide proper sample data and/or validation rules. Notice that `4+4+1=9` and not `11` characters. So what exactly are you trying to validate here.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question again, sorry long week. Let me know if I still don't make sense.

Comment: @doom, see edit.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated. I however need a data validation formula to insert into the custom validation option under excel tabs. This then pops an error message alerting the user they have broken a data insertion rule. The formula you have sent gives gives me an alert saying excel does not recognise it as a formula.

Comment: @Doom, there was a single semi-colon in there that I now replaced with comma. It should work unless you have a very old Excel **or** Excel for Mac.

Comment: Hi, I literally copied and pasted the formula and excel is complaining that it does not recognize it as a formula which it often does. I wish it would indicate what exactly about the formula it is complaining about.

Comment: Hi JvdV, do you possibly know how this formula can be adapted for google sheet use?

Comment: @doom I'd use Regexmatch for GS

Answer (score 0):

You have two formulas but no joining of them
IE you have an OR formula
=OR((LEFT(B2,3)="XXXX",LEN(B2)=11)
Which will return a true/false answer

You also have an AND formula
=AND(LEFT(B2,3)="XXXX",LEN(B2)=11)
Which will return a true/false answer

when you work through it you are being given a return of:
=True(or false), true (or false)
That isn't a formula and is causing the error output

I think you want to use an IF statement to join them and get an output as desired:
E.g.
=If(OR(LEFT(B2,3)="XXXX",LEN(B2)=11),AND(LEFT(B2,3)="XXXX",LEN(B2)=11), DO SOEMTHING IF TRUE, DO SOMETHING IF FALSE)

Comment: Left(B2,3) returns 3 characters which are then compared to 4. Did you actually test this?

Comment: That's not the cause of the error. The cause of the error is having an incorrect equation. The desired output would be wrong if using 3, but the formula would still work if used as I stated.

Comment: No need for the if() though.

Comment: Fair, depends what OP would like but your solution is good too to return a Boolean outcome. Nice. OP has been spoilt here. Haha

Comment: I sincerely apologise for the badly phrased question. My actual question is as follows; I actually want to force users to enter data in a specific row of cells in a sequence like HYPE1234567 i.e. first four characters must be letters then seven digits using custom data validation. Also restrict the total length entered into cell to 11 characters altogether (text (4) and numbers (7) combined).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
OR(LEFT(B2,3)="XXX",LEN(B2)=11,AND(LEFT(B2,3)="XXX",LEN(B2)=11))
```

It corrects the number of characters error and sorts the logic.